# Pass an NSString variable to a function and modify it

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new in objective-c, this is my first post. This is my problem:

In my main file I have a variable: NSString *var;
Then I have a function:

```
-(BOOL) myfunction:(NSString *)myvar {
myvar = @"OK!";
return YES;
}
```

Now in the main file I do:

```
NSString *var;
BOOL control = myfunction:var;
if(control)
  NSLog(@"var is: %@",var);
```

but the output is "var is: ". If I built in debug mode, and put a breakpoint at the start of function *myfunction* the memory address of *myvar* is equal *to var*, but after the assignment the address of *myvar* is different from the address of *var*. How can I solve it? thanks in advance!

Comment: By the way, that's a method not a function.

Answer (score 7):

While the answers given so far are correct. I think a more pertinent question is why you would want to do this.

It looks you want to have a defensive programming style where the return code indicates success or failure.

A more Objective-C like way to do this would be to pass the string and an `NSError **` as a parameter and return the string or a nil to indicate failure as described in the [Error Handling Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC)

So the way to write this would be:

```
- (NSString *)aStringWithError:(NSError **)outError {
    returnString = @"OK";
    if (!returnString) {
        if (outError != NULL) {
            NSString *myErrorDomain = @"com.company.app.errors";
            NSInteger errNo = 1;
            *outError = [[[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:myErrorDomain code:errNo userInfo:nil] autorelease];
        }
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

And to use it:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *stringVariable = [self aStringWithError:&error];
if (!stringVariable) {
    // The function failed, so it returned nil and the error details are in the error variable
    NSLog(@"Call failed with error: %ld", [error code]);
}
```

This is a trivial example, but you can see that you can construct and return far more meaningful information about the error rather than just whether it succeeded or not.

Comment: +1 correct, except that `newStringWithError:` should either return an owned object or be named something else.  You should also check `if (outError != nil)` before attempting to dereference it.  Dereferencing `nil` *will* crash your app.  Also, your `if(!returnString)` condition will always be false.

Comment: Good point about the name. Changed. I did check outError against NULL. In this case, as in the OP's answer, the function can't fail, but I was more interested in creating the NSError object.

Answer (score 4):

Syntactically you need to fix your myFunction invocation like so:
`BOOL control = [self myfunction:var];`

The real problem here is that inside of myFunction you are assigning a string value to a local string variable only, whereas you want to change the underlying string that it points to.  **This is usually the wrong approach in Obj-C**, but you can do it like so:

```
-(BOOL)myfunction:(NSString **)myvar
{
  *myvar = @"OK!";
  return YES;
}

NSString *var;
BOOL control = [self myfunction:&var];
if(control)
  NSLog(@"var is: %@",var);
```

Comment: To emphasize, if you are using *pass by reference, you are doing it wrong*.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `NSMutableString`.

```
-(BOOL) myfunction:(NSMutableString *)myvar {
    [myvar setString:@"OK!"];
    return YES;
}
```

and change your call site as follows:

```
NSMutableString *var = [NSMutableString string];
BOOL control = [self myfunction:var];
if(control)
  NSLog(@"var is: %@",var);
```